# Laravel - Validating correct format

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using Laravel 6.
Im trying to validate a input birthday. I want to validate it as d-m-Y, but as I know html input type date post default like: Y-m-d instead. When users get a suggested input like using chrome, it shows the right format d-m-Y. So how can i validate d-m-Y when html does the opposite?

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nickname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'birthday' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'nickname' => $data['nickname'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'birthday' => $data['birthday'] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data['birthday'])),
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a validation rule:

You can validate date with date_format or date validation rules. In order to satisfy those two validation rules, the field must be a valid date according to the strtotime PHP function. With date_format:format method you can set the preferred date format, and the filed value must match the given format.

```php
// with date 
$rules = [
    'start_date'        => 'date',
];

// with date_format
$rules = [
    'start_date'        => 'date_format:d/m/Y',
];
```

https://arjunphp.com/validate-date-format-laravel/

This may also work:

```php
$request->validate([
        'birthday' => 'date_format:d-m-Y'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validor should look like this

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nickname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'birthday' => ['required', 'date_format:d-m-Y'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

The birthday field under validation must match the given format.

> You should use either date or date_format when validating a field, not
>   both

. This validation rule supports all formats supported by PHP's DateTime class. read docs here [date format](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-date-format)

Comment: Even tho i use the date_format as you suggested, i still get the error:  The birthday does not match the format d-m-Y.

Comment: It might be the input birthday you are passing is in correct. Can you show that.

Comment: Im not missing it :/ Check this image:
https://gyazo.com/9e019945df5ca8334b2387f4b06d7e76

Comment: Wrap your date into string like this. date_format:"d-m-Y"

Answer (score 0):

You should use date_format:d-m-Y in your Validator.
And i suggest you to not use date and date_format together

Comment: Why would that be a bad idea?

Comment: Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-date-format